# Media query for scalable font size breaking text-align styling?

Tags: html, css

Trying to create a media query that for my email source code that will scale up the font size as the user's screen size gets smaller. This my media query:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<style type="text/css">.ReadMsgBody {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
.ExternalClass {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
.txtWidth {margin: 0 90px}
body     {width: 100%; background-color: #ffffff; margin:0; padding:0; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)  {
                body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0;}
                body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}
                img.deviceWidth.img {width: 150px!important}
                /*p.ContentWidth {padding: 0 20px!important}*/
        }

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
                body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0;}
                body[yahoo] .center {text-align: center!important;}
                img.deviceWidth.img {width: 130px!important}
                .txtWidth {margin: 0 0!important}
                .sig {padding: 0 0 0 40px!important; width: 100px!important}
                p {font-size: 120%}
        }
</style>
</head>
```

This seems to make the fonts scale properly but when I implement this, I lose a lot of the formatting further down the email. Specifically, this part where everything suddenly loses it centering and becomes left justified and I have no idea why.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<!-- / Cut out of the main bulk of email code here -->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px; text-align:center;">
<img src="http://images.gv-c.com/354/Images/12/qbp.png" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;">
<p style="margin: 5px 10px 10px 10px; text-align: center;">011-28 00 00 &bull; <a href="mailto:info@qstar.se">info@qstar.se</a> &bull; <a href="http://www.qstar.se">www.qstar.se</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="padding: 0px;" valign="top">
<img src="http://images.gv-c.com/354/Images/13/sidfot2.png" style="border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="600" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="center" colspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><span style="font-size:10px;">Du f&aring;r detta mail f&ouml;r att du har registrerat dig f&ouml;r &rdquo;Qstar Mailkvitto&rdquo;. Du har f&aring;tt detta mail till&nbsp;[DATA:EMAIL_ADDRESS].</span>
<br />
<span style="font-size: 10px;">[LINK:UNSUBSCRIBE=Klicka h&auml;r f&ouml;r att avregistrera dig fr&aring;n denna e-post-lista med erbjudanden och information fr&aring;n Qstar F&ouml;rs&auml;ljning AB]</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideas why this is? The square brackets designate variable fields that the email marketing platform populates and I can't see any other potential problems. It is definetely something to do with the media query as all the styling functions properly when I take out the "p {font-size: 120%}" line.